# Bootstrap Confidence Intervals in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

I am a new R user, and am having trouble using the boot package.  All I want to do is use bootstrapping to produce confidence intervals around a mean for a vector of numbers, such as:

```
x <- rnorm(100, 1, .5)
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Doesn't the following suffice?

```
library(boot)
x <- rnorm(100, 1, .5)
b <- boot(x, function(u,i) mean(u[i]), R = 999)
boot.ci(b, type = c("norm", "basic", "perc"))
```

Comment: What do the 'u' and 'i' indicate here?

Comment: @cryptic0: that is explained in `?boot`. `u` will be the original data (`x`, in this example), and `i` the vector of indices corresponding to a boostrap sample (the function will be called `R` times, for different samples). If the data is a vector, the bootstrap sample is `u[i]`, if it is a data.frame, it is `u[i,]`. (Of course, since `u` and `i` are the formal arguments of the function, they do not have any value outside this function.)